# Software markets for solo developer

Tags: solo-development

I want to create something useful of my own which others can use it. This can be free or it can make a little money for sustaining its development and increase income little. However, when think about the market, I don't know what market is lacking applications, what types of domain can be possible for a solo developer or small development?

For example, I can develop small game for the smartphone market, with me as the programmer, another person is graphic designer and another person is music composer, to create a functional and playable game. Or what types of domain/market in web development are possible for a single developer to produce a web application?

Or should I include the forth person, business man to identify this for me? If you have experience on this, I would love and highly appreciate if you share for me and everyone.

*EDIT:* I want to do this as my part time job, not the main job until it's possible.

Comment: Project suggestions and career advise are off topic, please read the [FAQ] thoroughly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but over the years, I tend to write frameworks and libraries to automate most of my programming tasks in a certain technology, then I try and sell those when I discover that they are actually quite useful.

Another thing you can do is to surround yourself with young entrepreneurs. They are always coming up with ideas for businesses. You then architect a solution to solve one of their problems and voila, you're in business.

I am not that good at coming up with new ideas though.

Comment: Nice advice. I like the part about hanging out with young entrepreneurs. Currently my domain is pretty limited. I only understand decently about game, but not other domains. Communicate with others people on other domains is a good way to have ideas.